Constant timeouts running Meta Llama 3.1 405B instruct
I am continually receiving this timeout error when trying to run the model in azure ai studio from my local machine in jupyter notebook.  I cannot find anything useful in the azure ai studio on why this is happening.
ServiceResponseError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxintstructxxx.eastus2.models.ai.azure.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=300)

This is the code snippet that is taking a very long time. It is the call to the API in the azure ai studio.  I have tried to use differing lengths of text, and it is all very slow.
Function to translate a batch of text using Llama 3.1-405B with the Azure AI interface
def translate_batch(text, temperature):
    messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": """
        You are a professional translator and book editor with expertise in cleaning up translated texts. Translate the text from PT to EN.  Do not add any additional comments to the text, just return the translated text.
        """},
        {"role": "user", "content": f"""
        I have an autobiography that needs to be translated from PT to EN. 
         Do not add any system comments and just output the translation. 

        \n\n{text}
        """}
    ]
    response = client.complete(
        messages=messages,
        temperature=temperature  # Low temperature for more deterministic output
    )
    return response.choices[0].message.content


After some digging into the internals of the Azure AI (and requests/urllib3) modules I found this piece of code.
connection_timeout = kwargs.pop("connection_timeout", self.connection_config.timeout)

if isinstance(connection_timeout, tuple):
    if "read_timeout" in kwargs:
        raise ValueError("Cannot set tuple connection_timeout and read_timeout together")
    _LOGGER.warning("Tuple timeout setting is deprecated")
    timeout = connection_timeout
else:
    read_timeout = kwargs.pop("read_timeout", self.connection_config.read_timeout)
    timeout = (connection_timeout, read_timeout)

Adding a kwarg read_timeout ultimately resolved the issue.
from azure.ai.inference import ChatCompletionsClient

...

    client = ChatCompletionsClient(
        endpoint="https://xxxxxx.eastus2.models.ai.azure.com/",
        credential=AzureKeyCredential("xxxxxx"),
    )

...

    response = client.complete(
        messages=messages,
        temperature=temperature,  # Low temperature for more deterministic output,
        read_timeout=3600
    )

